# primeng table:p-table row grouping width not working when scrollable enable

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng table with angular.Below is the code for using table:

```
<p-table [value]="cars" dataKey="brand" [scrollable]="'true'" scrollHeight="400px">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50px">Vin</th>
            <th style="width:50px"> Year</th>
            <th style="width:100px"> Brand</th>
            <th>Color</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template  pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-expanded="expanded" let-columns="columns">
        <tr class="ui-widget-header" *ngIf="rowGroupMetadata2[rowData.brand].index === rowIndex">
            <td colspan="4">
                <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
                    <i [ngClass]="expanded ? 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-down' : 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-right'"></i>
                    <span>{{rowData.brand}}</span>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <tr>
            <td>{{rowData.vin}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.year}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.brand}}</td>
            <td>{{rowData.color}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

As you can see the code above, I want to use row group with scrollable property.On running the application I found that width is not working(header width is working only).Below is UI on running application:
[image]

If I remove [scrollable] property from table, then width works you can see in below screen shot:
[image]

Comment: can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-scroll-rnhmug?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes I need scroll if records are more

Comment: Where scroll should be? for whole table or just the area expanded?

Comment: I need for whole table because user can expand all rows to see the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p-table` has class `ui-table` which as css property `table-layout: fixed`. This is the reseon you are getting the default result.

To get the result as per your widths, you need to have `table-layout: auto`.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-scroll-ssyhny)

Put below css in the component you are using `p-table`,

```css
p-table::ng-deep .ui-table table {
  table-layout: auto !important;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you have column value eceeding the column width, then for the colunm width to break your text, assign `word-break: break-all` to `td` elemets.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-scroll-aerpzj)

Comment: Found one issue with above solution, if any field value is large then cell width is not maintained.See below link for issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-scroll-srbohh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Actually the real problem is size. If you need size for columns then i think you should set column with word-wrap css property.

Comment: Tried css text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;but that has no impact.If I removed table-layout: auto !important; then it works

Comment: just adding `word-break: break-all;` solved the problem. https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-scroll-aerpzj. Updated the answer. Hope this helps. After this you might need to adjust text padding or text size.

Comment: yes it solves. I was thinking to show ... using css (text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;) so that row height does not affect.But the above css does not work with table-layout: auto

Comment: I found one solution and it is working for me by using colgroup

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by using colgroup(with columnresizable).Below is my final code.

```
<p-table [resizableColumns]="'false'" *ngIf="groupKey" class="png-table" [value]="data" [dataKey]="groupKey" scrollHeight="500px"
[scrollable]="'true'" [columns]="cols">
<ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
    <colgroup>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <col *ngIf="!col.hide" [style.width.px]="col.width">
        </ng-container>

    </colgroup>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns">
            <th [pSortableColumn]="col.field" *ngIf="!col.hide" pResizableColumn pReorderableColumn [class]="col.filter?'sortable':'non-sortable'">
                {{col.headerName}}
                <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
            </th>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
    <!-- <tr class="filter-row">
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [hidden]="col.hide">
            <input class="filter-input" *ngIf="col.filter" pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')">
        </th>
    </tr> -->
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-expanded="expanded" let-columns="columns">
    <tr class="ui-widget-header" *ngIf="rowGroupMetadata[rowData[groupKey]].index === rowIndex">
        <td colspan="7">
            <a href="#" [pRowToggler]="rowData">
                <i [ngClass]="expanded ? 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-down' : 'fa fa-fw fa-chevron-circle-right'"></i>
                <span>{{rowData[groupKey]}}</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.type">
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" *ngSwitchCase="'del'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <i class="fa fa-close delete-icon g-act-icon" (click)='deleteRow()'></i>
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" *ngSwitchCase="'edit'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <i class="fa fa-edit edit-icon g-act-icon" (click)='deleteRow()'></i>
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='type'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" [pEditableColumn] *ngSwitchCase="'cep'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <p-inputMask (keyup)="onEnterCEP()" mask="aaaaaa-999-999"></p-inputMask>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" [hidden]="col.hide" *ngSwitchCase="'cb'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" [pEditableColumn] *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='act'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='com'" [pEditableColumn] [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" [pEditableColumn] *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='tsk'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='sco'" [pEditableColumn] [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td classs="ui-resizable-column" [pEditableColumn] *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='hrs'" [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td  classs="ui-resizable-column" *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='des'" [pEditableColumn] [ngStyle]="getHeaderStyle(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>

        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

primeng using table  **display:"block"** style. Change it to **table**

```
 .p-datatable table {
   display: table !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[style.flex-basis]** in **th** and **td**

eg.

```
<th [style.flex-basis]="'5em'">Column 1</th>
<td [style.flex-basis]="'5em'">Value 1</td>
```

Ref: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10688#issuecomment-929915095